# Why do my hair and scalp feel greasy and itchy until I shower?

Tags: dermatology, hair, itching, scalp, greasy-hair

I've recently noticed that I have dry, itchy skin - particularly on my shins and ankles - and I think this may be caused by the warm-to-hot 10 minute showers I have every morning. The problem is that if I don't have these showers, my hair will feel greasy as soon as I wake up until I've had a shower. It's a hard sensation to describe, but it also feels like I'm very acutely aware of the hairs on my scalp, as well as the skin on my face. This is such an uncomfortable position to be in that it prevents me from getting anything done.

**Is this normal to feel after a shower? If not, what could be the cause of it, and how can I be free of it?**